# Firefox Glitch with custom jQuery UI Slider Handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am using the basic jQuery UI Slider for an audio player. I am using basic CSS to style the handle of the UI Slider and I have noticed that in Firefox, and ONLY in Firefox, there are some chunks of the graphic that I am using for the handle's background have been digitally removed. These glitches appear and disappear during the course of the playback as the handle moves along the slider, but like I said, this ONLY occurs in Firefox.

I have changed out the graphic from PNG to JPG, but I get the same results.

Has anyone else had this same issue?

[image: Example of handle Glitch]
Example of Glitch

[image: Example of handle Glitch]
What the handle **SHOULD** look like

Comment: A demo of this could be helpful

Comment: http://www.halleonard.com/jmj-sandbox/playbackplus/ Also, this only occurs on my PC version of Firefox, not my Mac version of Firefox.